# SD Maid on Rooted Roger's Galaxy S3 hanging on "System Cleanup" and "Duplicate"

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, performance, bugs

My phone is a rooted Canadian Samsung Galaxy S3 (SGH-I747M) running stock 4.4.2. I've had **SD Maid** installed for a very long time and it's worked great up until now. I've never had any issues with it. I hadn't used **SD Maid** in a couple of months due to carelessness so a couple of days ago I figured I'd give it a run.

Well, most of the scans to run as per usual but for some reason both "System Cleanup" and "Duplicate" seem to start but then shortly after hang and not complete. For example, I notice System Cleaner will start with a full 600 op/s but then it reaches the "cache" portion of the scan and then the op/s seem to drop steadily, all the way down to 5 op/s. I even let the phone sit for an hour or something, assuming for whatever reason, that the cache was massive but that doesn't seem to be the case. Shortly after, if you try to do anything, SD Maid crashes.

Something similar with the "Duplicate Finder" function happens as well. Start fast at around 120 op/s, gets to scan about 380-480 files and then the op/s drop to 2 op/s but the scanned files aren't moving at all.

I'm not sure if this is a bug with SD Maid, a problem with my phone or something else? I was curious about installing a older or beta version of SD Maid to see if that would help but I've been reluctant to do so. I've noticed my phone has also been somewhat more sluggish lately and that the battery has been dying much faster. I've been using Greenify for a year or 2 now and that always seemed to help. I added Hipmunk and Snapchat to the Greenify list a few days ago, thinking that they might be the culprits to the battery loss but it hasn't helped much.

How do I diagnose or fix SD Maid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an external sdcard in your device? If so, remove it and try again.
When sdcards start throwing errors and have to remap sectors it kills their performance. As this is usually an indicator for a dying sdcard i would suggest to backup any important data you have on it.

Comment: Oh my goodness, haha. It's the actual Darken! Hello! Anyway, I took out the SD Card and it instantly started working. I guess my SD Card is starting to go. No big deal. It's just a really old 2gig stick from my old Blackberry. Really appreciate this! It's always reassuring to have the actual developer help instead, lol. Love the product by the way. 10/10 would buy again! And the support? Amazing apparently, haha. Have an awesome day sir!